# Flipped image in PDFBox

Tags: java, spring, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to insert text into the PDF
using this but I am getting inverted text in the PDF

try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes))) {

```
        PDPage firstPage = doc.getPage(0);

        try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, firstPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true)) {
            contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 48);
            contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(3000, 1500);
            contentStream.showText(timestampText);
            contentStream.endText();
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        doc.save(baos);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
```

But I am getting this error:

[image]

how can this be resolved I am unable to move ahead......

Comment: Please try the `PDPageContentStream` constructor with the additional `boolean resetContext` parameter and set it to `true``. Does this improve the result?

Comment: As an aside, please don't post code as image but as text.

Comment: no that doesnt improve the solution instead i am not able to see the text now

Comment: Hhmm, I see you have coordinates 3000, 1000 - that seems unusual, in particular outside the visible page area. Have you checked whether the crop box of the page in question includes those coordinates?

Comment: then I assume this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27919730/535646